# Doctrine sql function withing addOrderBY

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am working with doctrine querybuilder and I need to include `->addOrderBy()` within my query,

So initly I had this

```
$qb->addOrderBy('a.weighting', 'DESC');
```

which worked fine but did not bring desired results, I went back to the drawing board and created new query and the `order by` part should look like this:

```
order by  DATE_FORMAT(published_at, '%Y/%m/%d') DESC
```

I tried to translate this into Doctrine queryBuilder but it does not work I probably doing something wrong:

My translated order by QUery Part:

```
$qb->addOrderBy('DATE_FORMAT(a.published_at, %Y/%m/%d)', 'DESC');
```

I tried Google for answers, went on to Doctrine web site : [Doctrine Site](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)

But still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Why you're trying to run MySQL DATE_FORMAT in Doctrine? Why not:
`$qb->addOrderBy('a.published_at', 'DESC')`
?

Comment: Because in order for me to retrive the data I need and have it in a order I need this is what i need DATE_FORMAT(), but Idont know how to translate this into DOCTRINE

Comment: But datetime is stored in database with format Y-m-d H:i:s. So ordering on that field will works fine (if hours produces problem, maybe you should use date field type?). But if you MUST use DATE_FORMAT, you should define custom DQL function. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html

Comment: first google result: http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/using-mysqls-date_format-in-doctrine-2-0/

Comment: yep it is the time that is the problem, thats why i need to use date format, any other way you can think off i can resolve this other than using date format..?

Comment: If you don't want to create custom DQL function, add special column for order purposes and in setPublishedAt update that field (it can be indexed integer (eg. value: 20140101) which is very fast;))

Answer (score 0):

Is published_at a valid Date field? Also a DATE_FORMAT will change it to a string and sort it like a string.